# why use std::atomic if it still requires a mutex to work properly

Tags: c++, mutex, atomic, stdatomic, stdmutex

Reading the text for [`std::condition_variable`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable) I've come across this sentence:

> Even if the shared variable is atomic, it must be modified under the mutex in order to correctly publish the modification to the waiting thread.

My question is this:

What is the use for atomics if not for "lock-free code to work with PODs"?

**UPDATE**

Looks like there's some confusion about my question :(

The "shared variable" in the quoted text is not the same as "condition variable". See this quote from the same page:

> ... until another thread both modifies a shared variable (the condition), and notifies the condition_variable

Please do not answer "[why we need to use a mutex with condition variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12551341/when-is-a-condition-variable-needed-isnt-a-mutex-enough/27694311)" or "[how the conditional wait works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47804723/how-exactly-does-the-wait-function-work-in-regards-to-condition-variables)" but rather provide information on how the use of a mutex "correctly publishes" the modification of an atomic to the waiting thread, i.e. whether an expression like `++counter;` (**not** the test like `if(counter == 0)`) would need to be done under mutex?

Comment: It's not the atomic that requires the mutex -- it's the condition variable.  Your actual question seems to have nothing to do with the information you quoted.

Comment: That text is specifically about `condition_variable`, not atomics in general. Atomic variables handle more stuff than just conditions.

Comment: I've updated my question to hopefully be more clear

Comment: Hmm I see you updated your question with a demand.  The modification of an atomic does not "publish" anything.  That is the job of the _signal_ (a.k.a. notify).  And the whole reason why you're getting answers about conditional wait is because that is precisely the issue -- the signal is atomic, but only if the handling of the dependent data inside the condition variable is atomic.

Answer (score 10):

The semantics of a conditional wait necessitates the use of a mutex.

This is because there is a potential race condition on the thread that is testing the condition.  When this thread is checking whether to wait, the following happens:

1. acquire exclusive lock
2. perform the test
3. either:

   a) release lock and wait for next signal

   b) keep lock and continue

Because step 1 acquires a lock, the whole thing is atomic, provided all other parties use the mutex correctly.

But what about when the variable being modified is an atomic?

> Even if the shared variable is atomic, it must be modified under the mutex in order to correctly publish the modification to the waiting thread.

Well, here's why.  If thread B comes along and modifies the atomic outside of the mutex, then steps 2 and 3 are no longer atomic.  Essentially, thread B can modify the value immediately after step 2 happens.  Then thread A will potentially make an incorrect decision in step 3.

Answer (score 1):

> why use std::atomic if [condition variable] still requires a mutex to work properly

There is no reason to use an atomic condition variable.

> What is the use for atomics

Even if atomics aren't useful for condition variables, they can still be useful for other use cases. A typical use case for atomics is implementation of a lock free queue.